# Творится что-то непонятное Visual Studio 15

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Код выдает неправильные значения, хотя должен работать нормально. Начал отладку, и тут выясняется, что вижуалка скачет по функции как ей хочется, вообще независимо от строк и функций. Какие-то пропускает, как ей хочется, на некоторые залетает по нескольку раз. Что за проблема понять не могу, гугл не помогает.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double f(double x) {
    return sin(x) + x * x;
}
double division(double a, double b, double(*f)(double)) {


double eps = 0.01;
    double c = a + b / 2;
    double fc = f(c);
    double x, y, fx, fy;
    while ((b - a) > eps) {
        x = a + (b - a) / 4;
        y = b - (b - a) / 4;
        fx = f(x);
        fy = f(y);
        if (fx < fc) {
            b = c;
            c = x;
            fc = fx;
        }
        else if (fy < fc) {
            a = c;
            c = y;
            fc = fy;
        }
        else {
            a = x;
            b = y;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

void main() {
    double a = -3;
    double b = 0;
    cout << division(a, b, &f) << endl;
}
```

Стоит отметить, что ранее все работало прекрасно, и никаких проблем не было.

Comment: Тут правильно? `double c = a + b / 2;`? Не `double c = (a + b) / 2;`?

Comment: @Harry более тупой ошибки я в своей жизни еще не допускал... Спасибо! Но почему вижуалка прыгала со строки на строку, пожалуй, для меня остается загадкой

Comment: Видимо вы отлаживали релизную версию с оптимизациями.